# when i running the model with OMshell scripts does not generate multiple random noises

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

In openmodelica, I made 5 random noise inputs and added globalseed module. When I simulated in openmodelica, it could correctly output 5 different random noises, but when I ran instructions in OMShell, the output result was the same noise. How should I solve this problem?Here's my model:

```
model Ocean_current_disturbance
  Modelica.Blocks.Noise.NormalNoise normalNoise annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-14, 56}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Noise.NormalNoise normalNoise1 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-12, -12}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput y annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {112, 56}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {110, 44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput y1 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {116, -12}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {110, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

 
equation
  connect(normalNoise.y, y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-2, 56}, {112, 56}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(normalNoise1.y, y1) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, -12}, {116, -12}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
end Ocean_current_disturbance;

model testn_5
  Ocean_current_disturbance ocean_current_disturbance[5] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-4, 6}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  inner Modelica.Blocks.Noise.GlobalSeed globalSeed(enableNoise = true, useAutomaticSeed = true)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-58, 58}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation

annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));
end testn_5;
```

Run in openmodelica:
[image: OpenModelica result]

Run the script in powershell:
[image: PowerShell result]

I want to generate 5 new random noises every time I run this model, but there is currently a problem in the output of the script run.

Comment: How does MOS.mos script looks like?

Comment: I only found problems with the output document data when I tried it in OMShell.

Comment: loadModel(Modelica)
loadFile("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/OptimizationOPT/test_n5.mo")
simulate(test_n5,outputFormat = "csv")

Comment: Maybe try with a command prompt started from OMEdit instead of a Power Shell (OMEdit->Tools->OpenModelica Command Prompt). I can't read the text on the Power Shell, but my guess it's not using the correct PATH variable. It could be, that the wrong C functions for randomization are used?

Comment: I regret that I have never used the openModelica Command Prompt in OMEdit for command line input, I will try to re-run my model to see if I can output the correct simulation results, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this. I used this script:

```
loadFile("T.mo"); getErrorString();
simulate(testn_5, outputFormat="csv"); getErrorString();
```

ran it like this:

```
adrpo33@ida-0030 MINGW64 /c/home/adrpo33/dev/Test/random
# time omc s.mos
```

and got this:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. I don't know where the problem is. Since the model itself is relatively simple, the script should not be a problem, but the fact is that the openmodelica run result is different from the OMShell script output data, and the openmodelica drawing interface result is the result I want.